# Is it necessary to use here double negative?

Tags: sentence-structure, negation, lists

> He never repeated the same story or **not** brought in the same set of 
>   characters.

I want to avoid the use of **nor**.
Then, is it correct to use double negative?

Comment: You wouldn't normally use ***nor*** or ***or not*** here.  You'd just say ***or***.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very confusing sentence. I think you're trying to say

> "He never repeated the same story and he never brought in the same set of characters."

But this is not what your sentence means. The way you have it right now, it means

> "He never repeated the same story and he has **never not** brought in the same set of characters."

This is the same thing as

> "He never repeated the same story and he always brought in the same set of characters."

If you want to avoid using "nor", just use "or" instead.

> "He never repeated the same story or brought in the same set of characters."

Here is a link on [nor vs or.](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/when-use-nor)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to avoid "nor?" I would endorse it over a double-negative.

I would offer the following:

"He neither repeated a story nor re-used characters." Never is now implied. The redundant use of "same" after "repeated" i is eliminated, because sameness is implied by the repitition.

Or

"He never repeated a story, nor did he re-use characters."

Again, this eliminates redundancy, and properly uses nor as a disjunction between the two negated alternatives.